# Prevent view from opening as modal view before data is loaded

Tags: ios, view, modal-dialog

I'm wondering if it's possible for a view to prevent itself from opening as a modal view before certain data is loaded.

For instance:

```
addTimeViewController = [[[AddTimeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddTimeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
addTimeViewNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addTimeViewController] autorelease];

Item *item = (Item *)[_dataModel.items objectAtIndex:_currentEditCell];    
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addTimeViewNavigationController animated:YES];

[addTimeViewController updateTime:item];
```

This will open the AddTimeViewController as a modal, but the AddTimeViewController has to load certain data before it's being displayed.

Would there be a way to prevent it from opening itself in a modal view before that data is loaded?
I want to do this inside the AddTimeViewController itself, I don't want to send out notifications and do it that way.

Comment: where is the data coming from and how will your app know when it is loaded?

Comment: What about adding some activity indicators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't prevent a viewController from loading itself, instead as the ViewController opens, you could add some intermediate views that will tell the user that you are currently loading data from a remote source

Comment: That's how I'm doing it right now, but I don't want to show the modal view while it's loading data, so the only way would to send out a notification and then open it as a modal view?

Comment: yes or adding a delegate to the new view controller, when if finished loading then open it, but what will you do instead of opening the view?

Comment: Well right now it shows a loading screen over the modal view, but i just want the modal view to appear, but i guess i can work with the delegate, would make it easier though

Answer (score 1):

Load New `ViewController` only when all the data task is completed.

If large amount of data is fetched from server, then you can have that in background thread -

```
Item *item = (Item *)[_dataModel.items objectAtIndex:_currentEditCell];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadNewView)
                       withObject:item
                    waitUntilDone:YES];

-(void)loadNewView {
    addTimeViewController = [[[AddTimeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddTimeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    addTimeViewNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addTimeViewController] autorelease];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addTimeViewNavigationController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I just set it up the wrong way, now my AddTimeViewController loads the data and handles it, I think I will use the delegate way suggested above